# How do I set the F77 environment variable to gfortran?

Tags: apt, gcc, c++

I'm new Ubuntu (and linux) user. In order to do my senior project, I have to install *psrchive*

I use this command to install psrchive

```
./psrsoft/bin/psrsoft psrchive --no-cfitsio
```

This is part of text which has been shown in terminal

```
checking that C++ and Fortran can be linked without conflicts... no
configure: error: 

The flags required to link the Fortran runtime libraries:

FLIBS= -L/home/boltfox/psrsoft/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath

cause the linker to choose the wrong standard C++ libraries.

Please see http://psrchive.sourceforge.net/third/cxx#f77


ex=$?
if [ $ex != 0 ] ; then
    exit $ex
fi
Build script failed!
```

so I go to http://psrchive.sourceforge.net/third/cxx#f77 and check my gcc and g++ version which is 4.8.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the specific commands you ran to get this error. Where are you defining `FLIBS`? Is that in a `Makefile` somewhere? What does this `$ex` scriptlet have to do with this? Whose exit status (`$?`) are you checking? How are installing `psarchive` etc. As it stands, we have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question,thanks for your comment